# Different time & date from the database and what shown at my web page using Spring MVC

Tags: java, sql, spring, datetime, jpa

I have some issue about my date & time that I've stored at the database (using SQL) it's different when I show it at my web page. There's different at date & time it self.

For example :

**Stored in DB** : 2023-05-20 18:12:48 (Right Date & Time)

**At Web Page** : 2023-05-21 01:12:48.0 (Wrong Date & Time)

I've set the default date & time based on right now time, so when the user click the button they will save the date & time by the time when they click at it.

The date & time that stored in database it's the right one. But when I show it at the web page, it's comes out different (wrong date & time at the page).

This's the entities table :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attendance_check_in")

public class AttendanceCheckIn {

     @Column(name = "check_in")
     @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
     private Date checkIn;

     //getter & setter//
```

I'am using SQL database and using Spring. Here's my controller that handle the save request to the database :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/attendance-input", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String inputAttendance(Model model, AttendanceCheckIn attendanceIn, Authentication auth) throws ParseException {

      model.addAttribute("attendanceIn", new AttendanceCheckIn());
      LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
      Date in = Date.from(ldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
      attendanceIn.setCheckIn(in);
      attendanceInServ.save(attendanceIn);

      return "redirect:/attendance";
 }
```

So, basically I've set the default value for date & time as right now time. So when the button clicked it's store the value, and the value that stored in database is right as what I want. This is the date & time that saved in database :

[image: value stored in database]

But when I see the value that render on the web page, this what I get :
[image: value showed at web page]

I checked my controller that handle request to show the data from the database :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/attendance", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String attendancePage(Model model) 

      model.addAttribute("attendanceIn", new AttendanceCheckIn());
      //Attendance Check In
      model.addAttribute("getAllAttendanceIn", attInServices.getAll());

      return "Attendance";
 }
```

And, this from table at my web page that using thymeleaf & bootstrap data tables :

```
<table id="attIn-table" 
       class="table table-bordered" 
       width="100%" 
       cellspacing="0">

     <thead>
        <tr>
           <td>Date & Time</td>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr th:each="as : ${getAllAttendanceIn}">
           <td th:text="${as.checkIn}"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Can someone told me what happened and how to solve this? Many Thanks

Comment: You can use another way for data-time storage if you want to use current date-time then don't use default current date-time value, Instead you can set value of that field at save time into service layer or any layer whenever you are writing logic of save record, So try this solution once hope it works!!

Comment: What database engine and version? And *exactly* what is the data type of your column? Voting to close as lacking debugging info.

Comment: I cannot imagine a scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now` is the right thing to do. That class cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. `LocalDateTime` contains a date and time-of-day but lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Comment: Both of the `Date` classes are terribly flawed. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the timezone where the application is executing is probably UTC-7. Then it converts it to UTC to get the date, which causes the date time to be displayed with +7 hours:

```java
      Date in = Date.from(ldt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

Then the date is correct, it is just expressed in UTC because that line is converting explicitly to it.

If it is not what you expect then convert to a Date using the local timezone. It is not clear why you are using java.time classes just to get the current date time if you are not really interested in converting to UTC timezone. A simple `Date in=new Date()`